# Ubuntu: downgrading Subversion from 1.6 to 1.5

Tags: svn, java

I installed Jaunty Alpha, and along with came Subversion 1.6.

My IDE (Intellij Idea 7) does not support Subversion 1.6, so I would like to downgrade my Subversion back to version 1.5.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

This problem is covered in the [IntelliJ IDEA FAQ](http://jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-1145).

Answer (score 2):

It is annoying, but SVN automatically updates working copies that it considers old. To revert your working copy files, a python script is distributed alongside the binaries:

- http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/tools/client-side/change-svn-wc-format.py

Once you've done this, you can re-install the older svn binary. You need to be careful if you have multiple copies of svn lying around not to use the wrong version!

(NB the server does not do this, so you can upgrade that AFAIK without problem). More useful info [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way that may be easier than change-svn-format.py:
http://www.admon.org/downgrade-svn-from-1-6-to-1-4/